# Synchronize Microsoft Dynamics CRM items with Outlook or Exchange filter user view issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I am going to set personal option setting. I have one user filter view called "My Outlook contact". I have modified the view query. I can see the changes in view but when I am sharing the same view with other user, query has been changed for user.

Is there any way to share same view with other users?

Please find the screenshot for more info.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD9ss.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVogE.png)

Thanks
Amar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit synchronisation settings for all users you must go to:

Go to Settings > Administration.
Choose the System Settings > Synchronization tab.

see also:
[System Settings dialog box - Synchronization tab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/system-settings-dialog-box-synchronization-tab.aspx)

Comment: I can share the "My outlook contacts" view to user but I am not able to share the same view which I modified. I have added some conditions in the view then I am sharing the view to user but user not able to see the modified view.its sharing the default view to users.

Comment: What is your intentention? If you wan't to modify Synchronisation settings for all users you must do this with System Settings Dialog. It does not work with sharing a view.